# Unable to insert data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm getting the following error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

My code is as follows:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1

    Dim conn As String = "Server=AKUSEKA-PC;Initial Catalog=ak;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    Dim objconn As New SqlConnection(conn)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim dt As Date

    Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePickerDOB.ValueChanged
        dt = DateTimePickerDOB.Value
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            objconn.Open()

            da = New SqlDataAdapter("Select*FROM details", conn)
            da.Fill(ds)

            MsgBox("open")    
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonSV_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonSV.Click

        Dim incmd As String = "INSERT INTO details" & "NAME,SURNAME,PHONE,[D.O.B]" & "VALUES('" & TextBoxNM.Text & "', '" & TextBoxSN.Text & "',
    '" & TextBoxPN.Text & "', #" & dt & "# "
        Dim cmdsql As New SqlCommand(incmd, objconn)

        objconn.Open()

        cmdsql.ExecuteNonQuery()

        objconn.Close()

        MsgBox("success")
```

Comment: Since your problem is in the application layer you'd probably be better served asking this on StackOverflow. That being said you're going to need to give more debugging information before we can migrate the question over. All you've given us is a generic error message. Without knowing your full error message no one is going to be able to help because your problem could be anything from a bad login to violating a FK.

Comment: If you want to ask questions about a problem with your code, you need to add the full exception/error message in the question. Otherwise people can only guess. So [edit] your question, paste the exception trace in the question and format the trace using the `{}` button. Also consider that this is dba.stackexchange which focusses more on database administration rather than the simple "my query threw an exception" style of questions. Questions like that are better served on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (if you do post it there, delete your question here).

Answer (score 2):

Might be just a bad connection string, but you've got a bigger problem: your input form is using form values in a SQL string without any validation or parameterization.

This means you are vulnerable to SQL injection, someone could write `;DROP TABLE details` in your form and you would be in big trouble.

It also means it is prone to simpler errors as well, if someone enters `O'Brian` in the last name field the resulting SQL string will be invalid.

Look up "SQL parameterization".

Comment: Agreed on the security aspect.  I would either create a stored procedure for whatever the action is, or have the DBA create one.  This way the only thing the application can do is Execute the SP and pass in the values necessary.

Comment: I can't believe that no one brought up [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) yet...